# Count case when exists

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this 2 tables. I want to obtain a third column in the first table counting the number of ocurrences in which table1.ca=table2.ca and table1.d<=table2.

Table 1:

```
CA  D
-----
CA1 4
CA2 5
```

Table 2:

```
CA  D
-----
CA1 2
CA1 6
CA1 10
CA2 3
CA2 7
CA2 11
```

Desired output.

```
CA  D   COUNT    EXPLANATION
----------------------------
CA1 4       2    There are 2 entries in table 2 for CA1 with D >=4
CA2 5       2    There are 2 entries in table 2 for CA2 with D >=5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a `LEFT` join of `table1` to `table2` and aggregation:

```
SELECT t1.CA, t1.D, COUNT(t2.D) "COUNT"
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t2.CA = t1.CA AND t2.D >= t1.D
GROUP BY t1.CA, t1.D
```

Comment: Thanks. Why is a left join needed and not just a join?

Comment: @banana_99 I guess you want all the rows of table1 and count = 0 if for a row there is no row in table2 that satisfies the conditions. If I used INNER join these rows with count = 0 would not be returned.